# Android WebView unable to execute Javascript when html has a special character &#x2713;

Tags: android, html, utf-8, android-webview, cybersource

Javascript is not getting executed when the below code is loaded in Android WebView.

Issue is seen only when the input box with a value of ✓ is being included in the html. Refer the text input field in the code given below with the name "utf8".

This input and its value is returned by a payment gateway provider, It's part of their form data, which needs to be submitted to their domain url to complete the payment. **Hence the value and the html cannot be altered.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action=“” accept-charset=“UTF-8” method=“post”>
    <input name=“utf8” type=“hidden” value=“&#x2713;” />
 </form>
 <script>
  alert("hello world");
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Issue is seen on :

- Samsung Galaxy S7, Android version 8.0.0
- One Plus 5, Android version 9

Working perfectly on:

- Motog 5s Plus, Android version 8.1.0
- Samsung J2, Android version 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to replace # with %23.

From Chrome 72 update webview treats the # as the end of content:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5656049583390720

Comment: Yes replacing the value works, but changing the value of the form data will fail the payment. Hence need a solution which works without alteration of the form data.

Comment: Agree. Chromium team suggests Base64 encoding the HTML content https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929083.

Comment: It works correctly without any issues, if loadDataWithBaseURL is being used, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the value like that?

And why not set the "type" as *checkbox* in your example?

You can set the checkbox as "checked" or "unchecked" simply by including "checked" inside the tag. e.g.

```
<input name=“utf8” type=“checkbox” value=“Buy_Milk” checked >
```

You can set the value attribute to something relevant, like say "buy milk", and you can check whether that's ticked using the *.checked* method in Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("utf8").checked = true;
//Do something if true

document.getElementById("utf8").checked = true;
//Do something else if false
```

There's no reason as far as I can see, to add the unicode reference as the value.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. In my case the html content was provided by a third party service with some silent form submissions. This scenario is really happening.

Comment: @Spectre I have now updated the question, mentioning the reason, why the value and the html cannot be altered.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue as soon as there's any hashmark characters in my webview. I thought i was only react-native + chrome 72 specific issue. Still an issue if you remove the # ?

([Is there anyway to display html with hashmarks (#) in react-native android WebViews where Chrome ver. > 72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549731/is-there-anyway-to-display-html-with-hashmarks-in-react-native-android-webvi))