# Is there anyway to display html with hashtags (#) in react-native android WebViews where Chrome ver. > 72

Tags: android, android-webview, react-native

I'm using a webview with a html-string that contains hashtags (#). This works fine in IOS and in Android where Chrome < version 72.
However when Chrome >= version 72 is used the hashmark will stop the rendering of the html.

I've tried both a standard react-native app (react native 0.57.0) and a create-react-native expo app(react native 0.57.1) and it's the same behaviour.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, WebView } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ html: "<html><body>123#456</body></html>" }}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 200, marginTop: 50 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Expected result: 123#456

Actual result: 123

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516798/webview-loaddata-not-working-on-8-1-and-9-0 but I guess there is no way of sending base64-encoded html to the webview?

Comment: And https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/298

Answer (score 1):

Workaround with replacing # with %23 seems to work in my case.
Will keep track of https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/298 for updates.